# c# initialization error when using INotifyPropertyChanged inheritance on class member

Tags: c#, oop, constructor, initialization, inotifypropertychanged

I have a `Main` class in which I define an instance of another class:

```
namespace testRun
{
    class Main
    {
        /// Initialize object to contain various project data
        public static CurrentState currentState = new CurrentState();
        ...
        public void Event1(object sender, Args e)
        {
            ProcessClear();
        }

        public static void ProcessClear()
        {
            currentState.quantityDictionary.Clear();
        }
}
```

And the `CurrentState` class looks like this:

```
namespace testrun
{
        public class CurrentState : INotifyPropertyChanged
        {
            /// Constructor
            public CurrentState() { }

            public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

            protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string property)
            {
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
            }

            private Dictionary<string, double> quantityDictionary;

            private Dictionary<string, double> QuantityDictionary
            {
                get { return quantityDictionary; }
                set
                {
                    quantityDictionary = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("QuantityDictionary");
                }
            }
       }
}
```

If I set `quantityDictionary`  as **Public**, I'm getting an error **"Object not set to an instance of an Object"** on the line `currentState.quantityDictionary.Clear();`

I think it's due to the face that `quantityDictionary` isn't initialized properly, but I'm not sure exactly how to do that correctly or if it needs to be done in the constructor itself or somewhere else. 
A bit confused on that...

Can someone help me put this in order?
Thanks

**EDIT :**

I've set the `quantityDictionary` field to **Private**, but if it's not **Public** then I get a `CurrentState.quantityDictionary is inaccessible due to its protection level` in the `Main` class on the line `currentState.quantityDictionary.Clear();`

Comment: Class fields are supposed to be a private, why `totalQuantity` is declared as `public`? There is also no `Clear()` method in `System.Double` struct. Does your code compile?

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski Thanks. I've cleared up and updated my post accordingly. My code compiles if the field is Public (runtime error), but not if it's Private (compile error).